# google charts - multiple linechart datatable with hidden lines for each chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

im trying to build a dashboard with one controller to rule several charts.
everything works but when I want to present different column on each chart things doesn't work out.

here is a snippent of whats wrong
http://jsfiddle.net/hzdyojca/

data table is hard coded an all columns exist when initialized:

```
['Date', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
[2004  , 3.5 , 5   , 4.4 ],
[2005  , 3.7 , 5   , 4.5 ],
[2006  , 3.7 , 5   , 4.6 ],
[2007  , 3.8 , 5   , 4.7 ]
```

As you can see chart A presents column 0 and 1 perfectly.
chart B is supposed to preset column 0 and 2 (date and A3)
and chart C is supposed to present some of them together.

```
        let chartB = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        options: options,
        containerId: 'chartB',
        view: {columns:[0,2]} //THIS DOESNT WORK
    });
    let chartC = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        options: options,
        containerId: 'chartC',
        view: {columns:[0,1,2,3]} //BUT THIS DOES WORK (OR EVEN [0,1,2])
    });
```

I don't understand how to make chart B show only the red line.

would appreciate more help.
thanks.

==========================================================================

a quick follow up:
so i understood that dashboards doesn't work with dataviews well so i tried skipping them but it still doesn't work:

```js
    google.charts.load('current', {
        packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
    }).then(function () {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Date', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
            [2004, 3.5, 5, 4.4],
            [2005, 3.7, 5, 4.5],
            [2006, 3.7, 5, 4.6],
            [2007, 3.8, 5, 4.7]
        ]);
        var options = {
            legend: 'top',
            chartArea: {
                width: '85%',
                height: '85%'
            },
            pointSize: 3,
            dataOpacity: 0.8,
            animation: {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'in',
                startup: true
            }
        };
        var colors = ['#b71c1c', '#1565c0', '#2e7d32'];
        var chartA = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartA'));
        var chartB = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartB'));
        var chartC = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartC'));
        var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
            containerId: 'control',
            dataTable: data,
            options: {
                filterColumnIndex: 0,
                ui: {
                    chartOptions: {
                        colors: colors
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'ready', drawCharts);
        google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', drawCharts);

        control.draw();

        function drawCharts() {
            var filterState = control.getState();
            var filterRows = data.getFilteredRows([{
                column: 0,
                minValue: filterState.range.start,
                maxValue: filterState.range.end
            }]);

            var viewA = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            var viewB = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            var viewC = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            viewA.setRows(filterRows);
            viewB.setRows(filterRows);
            viewC.setRows(filterRows);
            viewA.setColumns([0, 2]);
            viewB.setColumns([0, 2]);
            viewC.setColumns([0, 2]);
            chartA.draw(viewA,options);
            chartB.draw(viewB,options);
            chartC.draw(viewC,options);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="control"></div>
<div id="chartA"></div>
<div id="chartB"></div>
<div id="chartC"></div>
```

any idea why now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work, but there are bugs when using chart wrappers and views together

about all you can do is create the view, then convert it back to a data table before drawing

```
view.toDataTable()
```

which means you will need to draw the charts independently, instead of using a dashboard
this can be accomplished using the control's `statechange` event

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
    [2004, 3.5, 5, 4.4],
    [2005, 3.7, 5, 4.5],
    [2006, 3.7, 5, 4.6],
    [2007, 3.8, 5, 4.7]
  ]);
  var options = {
    legend: 'top',
    chartArea: {
      width: '85%',
      height: '85%'
    },
    pointSize: 3,
    dataOpacity: 0.8,
    animation: {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'in',
      startup: true
    }
  };
  var colors = ['#b71c1c', '#1565c0', '#2e7d32'];
  var chartA = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    options: options,
    containerId: 'chartA',
  });
  var chartB = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    options: options,
    containerId: 'chartB',
  });
  var chartC = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    options: options,
    containerId: 'chartC',
  });
  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'control',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 0,
      ui: {
        chartOptions: {
          colors: colors
        }
      }
    }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'ready', drawCharts);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', drawCharts);

  control.draw();

  function drawCharts() {
    var filterState = control.getState();
    var filterRows = data.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 0,
      minValue: filterState.range.start,
      maxValue: filterState.range.end
    }]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setRows(filterRows);

    view.setColumns([0, 1]);
    chartA.setOption('colors', [colors[1]]);
    chartA.setDataTable(view.toDataTable());
    chartA.draw();

    view.setColumns([0, 2]);
    chartB.setOption('colors', [colors[2]]);
    chartB.setDataTable(view.toDataTable());
    chartB.draw();

    view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3]);
    chartC.setOption('colors', colors);
    chartC.setDataTable(view.toDataTable());
    chartC.draw();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dash">
  <div id="control"></div>
  <div id="chartA"></div>
  <div id="chartB"></div>
  <div id="chartC"></div>
</div>
```

note: you will need to provide your own colors.
by default, each series is assigned a specific color, blue for the first
if the chart only has one column due to a view, it will be blue, regardless of which column it is